# Media Queries not working for responsive design

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am using canvas image for image display, It works great on large devices when it comes to small devices its not responsive so i used media queries for responsive design despite of using media queries still image is not responsive. I am using CSS class because i will be using this image layout in multiple places in a web page Please help me out in fixing this issue!

Thanks in advance!

### HTML code

```
<div class="img-container">
        <img class='img' src="http://lorempixel.com/320/480/" alt=""/>
        <canvas class="Canvas" width="320" height="480"></canvas>       
</div>
```

### CSS CODE

```
@media (min-width:480px) 
    {
        .img
        {
            margin-left: 30px;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
        .img-container
        {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: #1e74ff;
            position: relative; 
        }
        .Canvas
        {
            position:relative;
            z-index:20;
            width:100px;
        }
    }
    body
    {
        text-align: center;
        background: #f2f6f8;
    }
    .img
    {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
        margin-left: 103px;
        width: 350px;
        height: 428px;    
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    .img-container
    {
        display:inline-block;
        width:320px; 
        height:480px;
        margin: 0 auto; 
        background: #1e74ff; 
        position:relative; 
    }
    .Canvas
    {
        position:relative;
        z-index:20;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yb46yt0r/)

Comment: I think media query should look like `@media screen and (min-width:480px)` and to come after _master_ styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not targeting your image (.img) in your media query, but instead there appears to be a .dg-img selector. So probably all you have to do is change ".dg-img" in your media query to ".img".

Edit: Also place your media query below the "default" styles.

Edit 2: Your media query might be wrong. I assume you need "max-width:480px" for small screens, instead of "min-width"

Comment: Thanks @leon! I have changed my class selector to .img but still its not responsive on smaller devices.

Comment: Ah, in addition to my comment, what vivekkupadhyay said: Place your media query below your default styles. If you're styling .img for example within a media query, and below this there are more styles for .img, these will override the styles within the media query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use media query for smaller screens and remove margins and paddings and I set the width to fit the parent element If i got your question correct.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .img {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
}
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yonashailug/yb46yt0r/1/)